# Insert large set of data into a query without a loop in Coldfusion

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion

We have a page that has recently been timing out sporadically, It is really old code I never bothered updating, but now is the perfect time I guess.

What this code does is keep track of who gets an email sent to them from our email blast. The code:

1. Checks to see if they got the email already
2. Sends the email
3. Inserts into the email sent table that the member got this email.

Problem is that the query that marks the email as sent is inside a cfloop. I looking for advice on a better way to do this without putting the query into the cfloop, maybe some examples too.

It loops through about 6000 (a little under) contacts. Code is below.

```
<cfloop query="MembersWhoGetEMail"> 
    <cfquery name="queryname">
        INSERT INTO EmailsSent
            (EmailID, MemID)
        VALUES
            (<cfqueryparam value="#EmailID#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">, 
             <cfqueryparam value="#MemID#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">)
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

The server we have is running MS SQL 2012

Comment: What does the MembersWhoGetEMail query represent?

Comment: Is MembersWhoGetEMail a standard query object or did you create it on your own? If it is a standard one, you could simply do a `INSERT INTO EmailsSent (EmailID, MemID) SELECT (MembersWhoGetEMail-query)`.

Comment: @StefanBraun You cannot do that. You cannot use QoQ as a source to select records from and direclty insert them into a table using `cfquery`.

Comment: Where do you see a QofQ?

Comment: @Pankaj It is not meant to be a QoQ. `(MembersWhoGetEMail-query)` should be replaced with the SQL-query to select exactly this data. This way, ColdFusion does not have to handle all those 6000 entries. I'm sorry if the first comment did not state this clearly enough.

Comment: the MembersWhoGetEmail query represents who they want to send the email too. SpamOK people, small businesses, people who haven't received the email, etc. The query outputs results based on a drop down from the previous page.

Answer (score 2):

Looping over the data like that will grind the application server and cause the timeouts you describe.

Try this instead.
Create a stored procedure and let the DB server do all the work rather then get the data from the server pull it into the Cold Fusion application server then send it back to the DB

I would use a cursor in my stored procedure

```
set nocount on;

declare @email varchar(20);
declare @memid int;

declare insertCursor cursor fast_forward for
(your first select statement here)

open insertCursor
fetch next from insertCursor into @email, @memid

while @@fetch_status = 0
Begin
 INSERT INTO EmailsSent
            (EmailID, MemID)
        VALUES
            (@email, @memid)

fetch next from insertCursor into @email, memid
end
close insertCursor
deallocate insertCursor
```

Then in my cfm page

```
<cfstoredproc procedure="myProcedure" datasource="myDSN">
  <cfprocresult name="myResult"> 
  </cfprocresult>
</cfstoredproc>
```

This will allow your DB to do all the work while all the CF server is doing is waiting for it to complete.

**Edited- After discussing with Leigh my answer is way off base. In sorts.  This probably does needs to be done on the server as much as possible.  If your server is set up to send email then it could be done completely on the server. Using the sp_send_dbmail stored procedure

> Sends an e-mail message to the specified recipients. The message may
>   include a query result set, file attachments, or both. When mail is
>   successfully placed in the Database Mail queue, sp_send_dbmail returns
>   the mailitem_id of the message. This stored procedure is in the msdb
>   database.

And then you could schedule a job to run the procedure when required. The same as a CF task.

Comment: Why use a cursor? Set based is better.  *let the DB server do all the work* Agreed, but .. the above puts the cart before the horse ;-) From the description, the CF process determines which id's to `insert`. So those id's are not known until after the CF process runs. That said, agreed they could offload more of the work to the db.

Comment: Leigh - I was looking at the fact that they were looping over this query "MembersWhoGetEMail" which I assumed was already run on the DB and returned to CF. So in my example the creation of the cursor would actually use the query from "MembersWhoGetEMail" and then work of that dataset.  I am intrigued, I have not heard of set based.  What is that?

Comment: Databases are designed to work best with ["sets" of data, rather than manipulating "row-by-row" (like cursors)](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/writing-efficient-sql-set-based-speed-phreakery/). Because cursors operate on one item at a time, they are typically less efficient. Plus, in this case, a cursor does not buy you anything. The same result can be achieved with an `insert into/select`. *was already run on the DB* Yes, but then they do some processing in CF and only wish to insert back "successfully" processed items.  In theory, that may only be subset of the original query.

Comment: I see your point completely.  Yes now that you point it out, an insert into/select would do the exact same thing as my cursor.  Looking at the pseudocode above the code it looks like the entire thing could be done by the DB since they are on MSSQL 2012.  I assume that checking if they got the email is done on DB, the server could in theory send the email and update was well.

Comment: Exactly.  Though given that it is a legacy application, the simplest path may end up being a combination of the two: CF and db. Yet hopefully more streamlined than the original code ie 6000 inserts.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a large select list and insert in batch. You may need to loop through in batches of a thousand. 6000 probably won't work because [you can only pass 2100 parameters in a query](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f2ec73eb-f1e0-4048-95d0-1b1ff6c6fdf3/maximum-parameters-in-where-clause)

```
<cfquery>
  INSERT INTO EmailsSent (EmailID, MemID)
  <cfloop query="MemberWhoGetEmail">
    <cfset rowNumber = totalRow + indRow>
    <cfif rowNumber LTE totalRows>
      SELECT <cfqueryparam value="#MemberWhoGetEmail.EmailID#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">, 
      <cfqueryparam value="#MemberWhoGetEmail.MemID#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
      <cfif indRow NEQ rowsPerInsert AND rowNumber NEQ totalRows> UNION ALL</cfif>
    </cfif>
  </cfloop>
</cfquery>
```

Alternatively as Dan suggests, you could modify the loop to eliminate the if statement.

```
<cfquery>
  INSERT INTO EmailsSent (EmailID, MemID)
  <cfloop query="MemberWhoGetEmail">
    SELECT <cfqueryparam value="#MemberWhoGetEmail.EmailID#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">, 
    <cfqueryparam value="#MemberWhoGetEmail.MemID#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
    UNION ALL
  </cfloop>
  SELECT null, null WHERE 1 = 3
</cfquery>
```

Comment: You can simplify this approach with something like `select null, null where 1=3 <cfloop>union select etc`.  That would eliminate the need for the `<cfif>` tags.

Comment: I am not sure if the `2100` parameters limit is applicable to a normal query.
The official documentation from microsoft says the limit is for `stored procedures and user defined functions` only. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: I'm very sure.  In fact, I'm currently looking for a way to cope with it in my current task.

Comment: @DanBracuk does that work without a table to reference?

Comment: @DanBracuk good to know, I've added an additional solution into my answer

Comment: (Edit) *does that work without a table to reference* Depends on the dbms. For SQL Server, yes. Other databases, like Oracle, may require a table reference.  Also, as an aside `union` only returns distinct values. In cases where you want to preserve duplicates, use `union all`.  Though personally, I would use smaller batches and `in (....)` rather than looping.

Answer (score 1):

How about writing the fields into a csv file with `<cffile>`, then `BULK INSERT`?

> ```
> BULK 
> INSERT Employee
> FROM 'F:\\MyPublis\\CSVTest.csv' --location with filename
> WITH
> (
> FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
> ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
> )
> ```

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/775961/Import-CSV-or-txt-File-Into-SQL-Server-Using-Bulk

Answer (score 1):

The big question is whether or not the MembersWhoGetEMail query is (or can be) written as a single SQL query. If so, then a INSERT INTO SELECT query is your answer. If not, then writing to a CSV and doing a BULK INSERT is probably your best best.

INSERT INTO SELECT

I'm going to make up a simple query for MembersWhoGetEMail, but it can be any query that return the data correctly for the INSERT portion.

```
<cfquery>
 INSERT INTO EmailsSent
     (EmailID, MemID)
 SELECT
     EmailID,
     MemID
 FROM
     thisTable
 JOIN
     anotherTable
  ON
      thisTable.field = anotherTable.field
  WHERE
      1 = 1
</cfquery>
```

The SELECT clause can be any SQL at all that returns the correct number of columns and in the matching order to the columns being inserted. The data types must match the inserted data, so if they don't then you will need to CAST() or CONVERT() on those columns in the SELECT statement.

This will run much faster than looping over a query and doing multiple inserts.

If you cannot get it into a SQL query, then you will have to do a BULK INSERT.

BULK INSERT

In that case, you will write a CSV file and run a BULK INSERT on it.

```
BULK
INSERT EmailsSent
FROM '#FullPathToFile#'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

This will be a file with commas separating every value and a line return for every row with the first row being the names of the columns in your table.

In your example, you are just inserting integers, but if you were inserting text, then you would also need to take care that your text didn't contain carriage returns or commas or else it would mess up the CSV file (if so, you might have to choose different delimiters).

All in all, INSERT INTO SELECT is the better solution if you can get your data from a single SQL query.

Comment: Agreed. Also @Adam - is there a specific reason you must use a batch size of 6000? If you used smaller batches (100,200,...) you could use `where col in (.....)` for both the initial `select` and to insert the results as described above ie `insert into/select ...where col in (.....)`